# NAudio Strong Name Issue

Tags: naudio

I'm using NAudio (1.7.3.0) and NAudio.lame ( 1.0.3.3048 ) to convert Wav to Mp3 audio format.

My code(calling assembly) is strongly named , VS2015 complains that Naudio/NAudioLame dlls should be strongly named too, so I did singed Naudio dlls with strong name. now Unfortunatley I'm build error as

Note : I have strongly named both(Naudio) dlls.

Here is the code.

```
try
            {
 
                string filePath = @"D:\Lame\Wav\25mb.wav";
                string outputPath = @"D:\Lame\mp3\25mb.mp3";

                using (WaveFileReader wavReader = new WaveFileReader(filePath))
                using (WaveStream pcm = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(wavReader))
                using (LameMP3FileWriter fileWriter = new LameMP3FileWriter(outputPath, pcm.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.VBR_90))
                {
                    pcm.CopyTo(fileWriter);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Converted !");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Build error on :  **LameMP3FileWriter(outputPath, pcm.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.VBR_90)**

Error : *The type 'WaveFormat' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'NAudio, Version=1.7.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.*

Any help is appreciate !

Comment: The same code works successfully if the calling assembly and NAudio is NOT Strongly named.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your strongly named NAudio first, and then when you build NAudio.Lame, make sure it references your strongly named NAudio dll

Comment: Mark, im using Nuget pakages, do you mean to download the code and sign the assembly ? NAudio and Lame next ?